No continuous isomorphism from $O_4$ to $O_{3,1}$
I am hoping to show that there is no continuous isomorphism from the orthogonal group $O_4$ to the Lorentz group $O_{3,1}$. My approach so far is to make use of the fact that a matrix $A$ is in $O_{3,1}$ if and only if its columns satisfy the following with respect to the indefinite form $\langle u,v \rangle := u_1 v_1 + u_2 v_2 + u_3 v_3 - u_4 v_4$:
$$\langle A_{\bullet,k}, A_{\bullet, j} \rangle  = \begin{cases} 1 & k=j=1,2,3 \\ -1 &k=j=4 \\ = &k \neq j\end{cases}$$
Then, if there were a continuous isomorphism $\phi: O_4 \rightarrow O_{3,1}$ that sends a matrix $P \in O_4$ to a matrix $Q \in O_4$, we would have, for the fourth column in each matrix:
$$P_{14}^2 + P_{24}^2 + P_{34}^2 + P_{44}^2 = 1$$
$$Q_{14}^2 + Q_{24}^2 + Q_{34}^2 - Q_{44}^2 = -1$$
But at this point, I'm not sure how to proceed in showing that $\phi$ cannot be continuous. Any hint on where to go, either with my approach or with a different approach entirely, would be much appreciated!

It is much easier than that; already there is no homeomorphism, ignoring the group structure entirely. This is because $O(4)$ has two connected components but $O(1, 3)$ has four connected components.
Ignoring that and restricting attention to the connected components of the identity, they are still not homeomorphic because $SO(4)$ is compact but $SO^{+}(1, 3)$ is not.
Many variations on this argument are possible. For a more group-theoretic flavor, every one-parameter subgroup $\mathbb{R} \to SO(4)$ is a rotation and hence is periodic but there are non-periodic one-parameter subgroups $\mathbb{R} \to SO^{+}(1, 3)$, namely Lorentz boosts. (For a connected Lie group these two conditions are in fact equivalent to compactness and non-compactness respectively.)

 Strictly speaking this does not prove the desired result as stated until you show that a group homomorphism between Lie groups is continuous iff it is smooth, since until then "one-parameter subgroup" is ambiguous (does it mean continuous or smooth homomorphisms?) and so it's not clear if they're preserved by continuous isomorphisms, and in any case my claim above about one-parameter subgroups of $SO(4)$ requires differentiating them to prove (as far as I know). But I think it gives a clearer geometric sense of the basic difference between the two groups.

